# Inserting a block as a last child inside a selected tag using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I am working on a commenting module which is auto-refreshed every 5 seconds. The code is like this:

**jQuery Part:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
 $.getJSON('process.php?fooId=1', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(key,val){
       $('#abc:last-child').prepend('<div>some text</div>');
    });
  });
 }, 5000);
});
```

**HTML part:**

```
<div id="abc"></div>
```

What I need is, when someone comment, the comment must append into the div (`id="abc"`).

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

use `insertAfter()`

**official Documentation** : http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/

```
$('<div>some text</div>').insertAfter($('#abc:last-child'));
```

Comment: it won't work in my case because what I want is; the 'val' must be inside the like: <div id='abc'>'val'</div> If insertAfter is used, it will place the 'val' after this div and looks like: <div id='abc'></div>'val'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
     $.getJSON('process.php?fooId=1', function(data){
       $.each(data, function(key,val){
          $('#abc').last().append(val);
       });
     });
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: I have used both $('#abc').last().append(val); and $('#abc:last-child').append(val); but of no use. :(

Comment: also how are you sending the comment.

Comment: $.getJSON('process.php?fooId=1,comment=enteredComment'

Comment: this `comment=enteredComment` should be this way: `{"comment":enteredComment}`

Comment: OK, but that is not the problem, I am getting all the required value back after processing. What I need is to append all the data into this parent div(id='abc') but Its not working at all!

Comment: one more thing you could post a sample json from yours here at your post, just need to look at it, may be three or four will be good enough, if you can.

Comment: Okay! what happens `when you send a comment` at `process.php`, is it added in the json or it makes a new json for latest one only.